# how to bind a key to more than one operation in emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp

I've been using emacs for years, but I'm relatively new to customizing lisp (beyond plugging in lines from other emacs scripts / package installation instructions). I programmed scheme before, so I'm somewhat familiar, but that was also a long time ago.

How do I map a key to more than one operation? I'm adapting the cycle font sizes lisp code form:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CycleFontSizes

except that I would like to maximize the window (I'm using mac OSX) after font resizing.

I can maximize the window using maxframe:

```
(require 'maxframe)
(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'maximize-frame t)
```

How do I add this to the font size key bindings. I'd like to do something like:

```
(define-key global-map (read-kbd-macro "C-0")   
  (lambda()
    'font-zoom-reset-font-size
    (add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'maximize-frame t))
)
```

This isn't correct because define-key is expecting a different type. This is probably pretty trivial after seeing an example...

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

You're very close -- just need to define your function as being interactive by including the one line `(interactive)` and make the call to `font-zoom-reset-font-size` actually call the function, not just a reference to the function:

```
(define-key global-map (read-kbd-macro "C-0")   
  (lambda()
    (interactive)
    (font-zoom-reset-font-size)
    (add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'maximize-frame t))
)
```

**Original (and still valid) answer**

You can define a function with your multiple steps and then bind the key to that function. Something like:

```
(defun zoom-font-and-max()
  (interactive)
  (font-zoom-reset-font-size)
  (add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'maximize-frame t))


(global-set-key (kbd "C-0") 'zoom-font-and-max)
```